# Importing modules with yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks vscode command in latest version of TypeScript does not resolve issue TS2307

Tags: typescript, yarnpkg, hadoop-yarn

I'm using yarn version 3.5.0 and my IDE is using vscode. To tell vscode that I'm using yarn berry, I use the command `yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks vscode`, and it works in TypeScript version 5.0.4, but when I raise the TypeScript version, it doesn't work and all my import statements are redlined. Do you have any idea why this is happening?

I ran the commands below, starting with the most recent version of Typescript and working my way down.

```
yarn remove typescript
rm -rf .yarn/sdks/typescript
yarn add -D typescript@5.0.4 // -> specific version of typescript
yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks vscode
```